# Bootstrap col class doesn't work

Tags: css, twitter-bootstrap

I'm learning web development.I try to make three div in one row with bootstrap col class, but it doesn't work, two divs in a row leaving some blank and the other div in a new line.I made a fixed width with three divs to achieve the layout but I don't think it's a regular method.
It maybe the CSS property 'box-sizing', I set it 'border-box',it doesn't work.

my page.
https://aura-zx.github.io/coursera-front-end-basic/module3-solution/index.html

Comment: The problem is that you've added custom margins, and borders to your columns. Both of these add width that conflicts with the BootStrap columns. As a third point, all BootStrap columns additionally need to be inside a class of `.row`, which gives negative margins to accommodate the margins created by the columns :)

Comment: Also, your page is titled **Assignment Solution**, so you're expected to [**do a lot of research yourself**](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/261592). I'd recommend going back and reading the [**Bootstrap examples**](http://getbootstrap.com/getting-started/). For further information, please see [**how to ask good questions**](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask), and take the [**tour**](http://stackoverflow.com/tour) of the site :)

Comment: @ObsidianAge Thanks for your comment, it's very useful and full of details. And also thanks for the advice, I'll do that :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem is in your custom style file `style.css` in line `~58`

```
.item{
    margin: 5px 5px 5px 0;
}
```

You should not use that, you should also use `col` inside a`div.row`

```css
body {
  font-size: 16px;
  font-family: 'Oxygen', sans-serif;
}


/** HEADER **/

#header-nav {
  background-color: #f6b319;
  border-radius: 0;
  border: 0;
}

.navbar-brand h1 {
  font-family: 'Lore', serif;
  color: purple;
  font-size: 1.5em;
  text-transform: uppercase;
  font-weight: bold;
  text-shadow: 1px 1px 1px #222;
  margin-top: 0;
  margin-bottom: 0;
  line-height: .75;
}

.navbar-brand a:hover,
.navbar-brand a:focus {
  text-decoration: none;
}

#nav-list a {
  color: #951c49;
  text-align: center;
}

#nav-list a:hover {
  background: #e7e7e7;
}

#nav-list a span {
  font-size: 1.8em;
}

#nav-list li {
  padding: 0;
}

.navbar-header button.navbar-toggle,
.navbar-header .iconbar {
  border: 1px solid #61122f;
}

.navbar-header button.navbar-toggle {
  /* after clear, button own a new line*/
  clear: both;
  /* reduce margin-top can make them in one line.*/
  margin-top: -40px;
}

body h1 {
  color: black;
}

.item {
  background-color: grey;
  box-sizing: border-box;
}

@media (min-width: 1200px) {
  .item {
    border: 1px solid black;
    margin: 5px 5px 5px 0;
    padding: 5px;
  }
}

@media (min-width: 992px) and (max-width: 1199px) {
  .item {
    border: 1px solid black;
    margin: 5px 5px 5px 0;
    padding: 5px;
  }
}

@media (min-width: 768px) and (max-width: 991px) {
  .item {
    border: 1px solid black;
    margin: 5px 5px 5px 0;
    padding: 5px;
  }
  #chicken {
    width: 355px;
  }
  #beaf {
    width: 355px;
  }
  #sushi {
    clear: both;
  }
}

@media (max-width: 767px) {
  #main-content {
    margin: 30px;
  }
}
```

```html
<html lang="en">

<head>
  <meta charset="utf-8">
  <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
  <title>Assignment Solution for Module 3</title>
</head>

<body>
  <header>
    <nav id="header-nav" class="navbar navbar-default">
      <div class="container">
        <div class="navbar-header">
          <div class="navbar-brand">
            <a href="#">
              <h1>Food,LLC</h1>
            </a>
          </div>

          <button type="button" class="navbar-toggle collapsed" data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#collapsable-nav" aria-expanded="false">
            <span class="sr-only">Toggle navigation</span>
            <span class="icon-bar"></span>
            <span class="icon-bar"></span>
            <span class="icon-bar"></span>
        </button></div>

        <div id="collapsable-nav" class="collapse navbar-collapse">
          <ul id="nav-list" class="nav navbar-nav navbar-right">
            <li class="active">
              <a href="#" class="visible-xs"><br>Chicken</a>
            </li>
            <li>
              <a href="#" class="visible-xs"><br>Beaf</a>
            </li>
            <li>
              <a href="#" class="visible-xs"><br>Sushi</a>
            </li>
          </ul>

        </div>
      </div>
      <!-- .container -->
    </nav>
    <!-- #header-nav -->
  </header>
  <h1 class="text-center">Our Menu</h1>
  <div id="main-content" class="container">
    <div class="row">
      <div id="chicken" class="col-md-4 col-sm-6">
        <div class="item">
          <h3 class="text-center">Chicken</h3>
          <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit. Eaque inventore esse minima incidunt impedit. Asperiores, voluptatem. Sint aspernatur provident, rem odio dolorem eaque voluptatibus modi reprehenderit minima, itaque cupiditate totam.Asperiores,
            voluptatem. Sint aspernatur provident, rem odio dolorem eaque voluptatibus modi reprehenderit minima, itaque cupiditate totam.Asperiores, voluptatem. Sint aspernatur provident, rem odio dolorem eaque voluptatibus modi reprehenderit minima,
            itaque cupiditate totam. Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit. Eaque inventore esse minima incidunt impedit. Asperiores, voluptatem. Sint aspernatur provident, rem odio dolorem eaque voluptatibus modi reprehenderit minima,
            itaque cupiditate totam.Asperiores, voluptatem. Sint aspernatur provident, rem odio dolorem eaque voluptatibus modi reprehenderit minima, itaque cupiditate totam.Asperiores, voluptatem. Sint aspernatur provident, rem odio dolorem eaque voluptatibus
            modi reprehenderit minima, itaque cupiditate totam. Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit. Eaque inventore esse minima incidunt impedit. Asperiores, voluptatem. Sint aspernatur provident, rem odio dolorem eaque voluptatibus
            modi reprehenderit minima, itaque cupiditate totam.Asperiores, voluptatem. Sint aspernatur provident, rem odio dolorem eaque voluptatibus modi reprehenderit minima, itaque cupiditate totam.Asperiores, voluptatem. Sint aspernatur provident,
            rem odio dolorem eaque voluptatibus modi reprehenderit minima, itaque cupiditate totam. Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit. Eaque inventore esse minima incidunt impedit. Asperiores, voluptatem. Sint aspernatur provident,
            rem odio dolorem eaque voluptatibus modi reprehenderit minima, itaque cupiditate totam.Asperiores, voluptatem. Sint aspernatur provident, rem odio dolorem eaque voluptatibus modi reprehenderit minima, itaque cupiditate totam.Asperiores, voluptatem.
            Sint aspernatur provident, rem odio dolorem eaque voluptatibus modi reprehenderit minima, itaque cupiditate totam. Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit. Eaque inventore esse minima incidunt impedit. Asperiores, voluptatem.
          </p>
        </div>
      </div>
      <div id="beaf" class="col-md-4 col-sm-6">
        <div class="item">
          <h3 class="text-center">Beaf</h3>
          <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit. Eaque inventore esse minima incidunt impedit. Asperiores, voluptatem. Sint aspernatur provident, rem odio dolorem eaque voluptatibus modi reprehenderit minima, itaque cupiditate totam.Asperiores,
            voluptatem. Sint aspernatur provident, rem odio dolorem eaque voluptatibus modi reprehenderit minima, itaque cupiditate totam.Asperiores, voluptatem. Sint aspernatur provident, rem odio dolorem eaque voluptatibus modi reprehenderit minima,
            itaque cupiditate totam. Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit. Eaque inventore esse minima incidunt impedit. Asperiores, voluptatem. Sint aspernatur provident, rem odio dolorem eaque voluptatibus modi reprehenderit minima,
            itaque cupiditate totam.Asperiores, voluptatem. Sint aspernatur provident, rem odio dolorem eaque voluptatibus modi reprehenderit minima, itaque cupiditate totam.Asperiores, voluptatem. Sint aspernatur provident, rem odio dolorem eaque voluptatibus
            modi reprehenderit minima, itaque cupiditate totam. Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit. Eaque inventore esse minima incidunt impedit. Asperiores, voluptatem. Sint aspernatur provident, rem odio dolorem eaque voluptatibus
            modi reprehenderit minima, itaque cupiditate totam.Asperiores, voluptatem. Sint aspernatur provident, rem odio dolorem eaque voluptatibus modi reprehenderit minima, itaque cupiditate totam.Asperiores, voluptatem. Sint aspernatur provident,
            rem odio dolorem eaque voluptatibus modi reprehenderit minima, itaque cupiditate totam. Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit. Eaque inventore esse minima incidunt impedit. Asperiores, voluptatem. Sint aspernatur provident,
            rem odio dolorem eaque voluptatibus modi reprehenderit minima, itaque cupiditate totam.Asperiores, voluptatem. Sint aspernatur provident, rem odio dolorem eaque voluptatibus modi reprehenderit minima, itaque cupiditate totam.Asperiores, voluptatem.
            Sint aspernatur provident, rem odio dolorem eaque voluptatibus modi reprehenderit minima, itaque cupiditate totam. Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit. Eaque inventore esse minima incidunt impedit. Asperiores, voluptatem.
          </p>
        </div>
      </div>
       <div id="sushi" class="col-md-4 col-sm-6">
        <div class="item">
          <h3 class="text-center">Sushi</h3>
          <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit. Eaque inventore esse minima incidunt impedit. Asperiores, voluptatem. Sint aspernatur provident, rem odio dolorem eaque voluptatibus modi reprehenderit minima, itaque cupiditate totam.Asperiores,
            voluptatem. Sint aspernatur provident, rem odio dolorem eaque voluptatibus modi reprehenderit minima, itaque cupiditate totam.Asperiores, voluptatem. Sint aspernatur provident, rem odio dolorem eaque voluptatibus modi reprehenderit minima,
            itaque cupiditate totam. Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit. Eaque inventore esse minima incidunt impedit. Asperiores, voluptatem. Sint aspernatur provident, rem odio dolorem eaque voluptatibus modi reprehenderit minima,
            itaque cupiditate totam.Asperiores, voluptatem. Sint aspernatur provident, rem odio dolorem eaque voluptatibus modi reprehenderit minima, itaque cupiditate totam.Asperiores, voluptatem. Sint aspernatur provident, rem odio dolorem eaque voluptatibus
            modi reprehenderit minima, itaque cupiditate totam. Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit. Eaque inventore esse minima incidunt impedit. Asperiores, voluptatem. Sint aspernatur provident, rem odio dolorem eaque voluptatibus
            modi reprehenderit minima, itaque cupiditate totam.Asperiores, voluptatem. Sint aspernatur provident, rem odio dolorem eaque voluptatibus modi reprehenderit minima, itaque cupiditate totam.Asperiores, voluptatem. Sint aspernatur provident,
            rem odio dolorem eaque voluptatibus modi reprehenderit minima, itaque cupiditate totam. Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit. Eaque inventore esse minima incidunt impedit. Asperiores, voluptatem. Sint aspernatur provident,
            rem odio dolorem eaque voluptatibus modi reprehenderit minima, itaque cupiditate totam.Asperiores, voluptatem. Sint aspernatur provident, rem odio dolorem eaque voluptatibus modi reprehenderit minima, itaque cupiditate totam.Asperiores, voluptatem.
            Sint aspernatur provident, rem odio dolorem eaque voluptatibus modi reprehenderit minima, itaque cupiditate totam. Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit. Eaque inventore esse minima incidunt impedit. Asperiores, voluptatem.
          </p>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
  <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
  <script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
  <link href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet" />
</body>

</html>
```